# Why does Sound Search Widget Keep Disappearing?

Tags: google, app-widgets

Ever since I got the phone and continuing to this day, if I reboot the phone the Google Sound Search widget disappears from my home screen. I reinstall it from the widgets menu, and it's all good--until next time the phone restarts, and then it's deja vu, gone again!

Sometimes I don't notice until I need the widget. That's usually when I'm driving and hear a song I like on the radio. I can't safely reinstall a widget while driving so this is not good.

Is there any logical reason for this? Any way to prevent it?

I'm using a Nokia 7.2 running Android 10. I've had the phone about six months.
Currently the phone has build number 00WW_2_400_SP02 based on the "about device" info in the settings menu.

Other widgets I use do not have this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem. All you need to do is clear the data of Google play services and redownload it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! When I go to clear the data, should I hit "clear cache" or " clear storage" or both? Any idea why this works?

Comment: Hit clear cache and try, if it does not work then clear storage. All Google apps work through Google play services. These services store server and user data. Sometimes these play services get bugged because of corrupted cache, you just need to clear it from time to time

Comment: I appreciate your suggestion and thank you for your time. Unfortunately this did not work for me. I cleared the cache from Google Play services, and rebooted. Widget disappeared. I reinstalled the widget, and then cleared the storage from Google play services. Rebooted again, and the widget was gone again!